# Homomorphism of representations

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, representation-theory

I am studying representation theory. Consider that $V$ and $W$ are two finite dimension vector spaces such that $V$ is isomorphic to $W$. Consider also that $A$ is an algebra. I would like to know If exists an homomorphism of representations
$$\phi: V \to W$$

such that $\phi(av) = a\phi(v)$ to $v \in V $ and $\phi \neq 0$

Thank you in advance

Comment: You seem to be missing something in the setup: it sounds like you also want an action of $A$ on $V$ and $W$. If so, take $\phi$ to be the zero homomorphism.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan I edit my question. I need $\phi \neq 0 $. Thank you.

Comment: $\phi$ is still not guaranteed to be an isomorphism in general. For example we can take $A = k$ to be the ground field and $\phi$ to be any linear map which is nonzero but not invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Let $A=\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2-1)$. Let $V$ be the one dimensional $A$-module with $x.v=v$ for all $v\in V$, and let $W$ be the one dimensional $A$-module with $x.w=-w$ for all $w\in W$. Then $V$ and $W$ are linearly isomorphic, but they are not isomorphic as $A$-modules.